# 500 error on /tools/post-feedback

Tags: bug, 10k-tools, 500-server-error

Whenever I try to load https://stackoverflow.com/tools/post-feedback, it stalls for 30 seconds and then I get the "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" error. (I can't try on other sites because I don't have 10k rep.) What's going on? Is it just me?

Comment: This seems to be specific to Stack Overflow. I tried it here on Meta (the sole site where I have 10k+ rep) and I couldn't reproduce here.

Comment: That sounds like a classic case of the page taking forever to load all the data and then sending a 500 because it kills the request after so long.

Comment: @tbodt I just tried it with Math where I have over 10k rep., with it showing properly after taking only a few seconds to load. Also, clicking on the various tabs (i.e., underrated, overrated, most helpful & least helpful) all worked fairly quickly.

Comment: MSO Duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397989/6083675